# How can we unpack a JSON file from an HTTP request

Tags: ballerina

[{"EmployeeID":1,"Name":"Alice","Age":20,"SSN":123456789}]

This is JSON file returned from a SQL query.
I want to extract the name from this JSON file

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

As this returns a set of records from the table, indexing can be used as follows

var employee = retrieveById(empID); // returns as an array of records

string employeeName = employee[0].Name; // to extract the name from the 0th index(1st             record)